# Uploaded image not save to wordpress from mac apple system

Tags: wordpress

Uploaded image not save to wordpress from mac apple system.I tested into linux system and window system and it was worked fine.
But issue for Mac.
Any suggestion that how i can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me more like a connection issue, There should be no reaseon as to why you can't upload an image to WordPress using a Mac. Even try another browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tested with network connection and also in all browsers. Can chat with private connection with you so i can send a video that i have an issue ?